# Azure login Issue from MVC Website

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure

I am developing a website in which Login is through Azure. When I click on Login button of my website, it takes me to Microsoft website where I type my userId and Password. Microsoft authenticates it and returns back to my website but Request.IsAuthenticate is still false. Website is running on local but not when hosted to azure server.

Web.Config:

> authentication mode="None"/

I am stuck up with this issue since 15 days. Can someone please help me on this..
Thanks..

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question. Otherwise you risk of the question being closed.

Comment: Seconding FriendFX's comment, please add some of the code you are using in your app for authentication, and the code where it is working as well as the code where it is not working.